I want to minimize predicted_Pel obtained from neural network by using 2 decision variables
I want to minimize predicted_Pel obtained from neural network by using 2 decision variables, the following code is working with one decision variable while it is not working with 2 variables and showing error,

It is my dataset that I trained in neural network

import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from gekko.ML import Gekko_NN_SKlearn, CustomMinMaxGekkoScaler
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.neural_network import MLPRegressor
from gekko import GEKKO
data = {
    'Tco': [303.9599915, 303.6700134, 303.5799866, 303.7799988, 303.8200073, 304.1000061, 304.0400085, 304.0,
            303.9500122, 304.25],
    'Tei': [287.8900146, 287.8399963, 287.7799988, 287.8099976, 287.8299866, 287.8200073, 287.8399963, 287.8900146,
            287.8399963, 287.8800049],
    'm_cond': [0.000259306, 0.000266121, 0.000265435, 0.000266299, 0.000266172, 0.000266147, 0.000266071, 0.000266147,
               0.000266757, 0.000267444],
    'Pel': [874.0000129, 873.0000257, 871.999979, 875.9999871, 878.000021, 885.9999776, 884.9999905, 883.0000162,
            882.0000291, 889.9999857]
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
# Define features and label
X = ['Tco','Tei', 'm_cond']
Y = ['Pel']


After training my neural network, I am minimizing predicted Pel, it is working with one decision variable i.e Tco as in the following

# Create a Gekko model
m = GEKKO()

# Define Tco as a decision variable
Tco = m.Var(value=10, lb=303, ub=304)

# Predict Pel using the trained neural network 
predicted_Pel = Gekko_NN_SKlearn(mlp, mma, m).predict([Tco])

# Set the predicted Pel value as the objective to minimize
m.Minimize(predicted_Pel)

# Solve the optimization problem
m.solve(disp=False)

# Print the optimized Tco and corresponding predicted Pel value
print('Optimized Tco:', Tco.value[0])
print('Optimized Predicted Pel:', predicted_Pel.value[0])
print('Gekko Solvetime:', m.options.SOLVETIME, 's')                           

Solution
Optimized Tco: 303.5799866
Optimized Predicted Pel: 875.45941052
Gekko Solvetime: 0.056699999986 s

It is not working when I use 2 decison variables i.e Tco and Tei as in the following

# Create a Gekko model
m = GEKKO()

# Define Tco as a decision variable
Tco = m.Var(value=10, lb=303, ub=304)
Tei= m.Var(value=10, lb=287, ub=288)

# Predict Pel using the trained neural network 
predicted_Pel = Gekko_NN_SKlearn(mlp, mma, m).predict([Tco, Tei])

# Set the predicted Pel value as the objective to minimize
m.Minimize(predicted_Pel)

# Solve the optimization problem
m.solve(disp=False)

# Print the optimized Tco and corresponding predicted Pel value
print('Optimized Tco:', Tco.value[0])
print('Optimized Predicted Pel:', predicted_Pel.value[0])
print('Gekko Solvetime:', m.options.SOLVETIME, 's')

ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (3,) (2,)
I want to get solution with 2 or more decision variables.

Thank you for your question and helpful code snippets. I wrote up a quick scaling / training script that generates the mlp and mma objects, using the Tco and Tei as input features:
#train mlp 2 features
Xs = ['Tco','Tei']

mlp = MLPRegressor(hidden_layer_sizes=[16])
s = CustomMinMaxGekkoScaler(df,Xs,Y)
ds = s.scaledData()
mma = s.minMaxValues()

mlp.fit(ds[Xs],ds[Y])

After running your last block of code, it outputs the following result:
Optimized Tco: 303.2153289
Optimized Predicted Pel: 876.14340232
Gekko Solvetime: 0.042400000006 s

My guess is that when you trained the mlp object, you trained it on all 3 input features, rather than just the 2 you use as decision variables, which causes the ValueError. If you choose to use the 3-input model, you would also have to include the additional input, which I assume is 'm_cond', as a constant or another decision variable, like so:
m_cond = 0.000266172
# Predict Pel using the trained neural network 
predicted_Pel = Gekko_NN_SKlearn(mlp, mma, m).predict([Tco, Tei,m_cond])

Hopefully this response is helpful.
